# How to select and highlight a single cell in HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to select a cell in a HTML table when clicking on it.
Currently I use this:

```
$("td").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
});​
```

an my css is:

```
td:hover, td.selected {
   background-color: #FF9900
}
td {padding: 5px;}
```

Hovering works just fine, but when I click on a cell it won't stay select.

How can I fix it

**EDIT**

You're right I shoud have give you more background info. I have to do a JavaFx programm for University. But JavaFX doesn't provide a table I wanted. So I decided get a WebView I this part of the application and make the table via a StringBuilder. In the following you see my current output (in the header is normaly the css and script link deleted it for this):
https://jsfiddle.net/5c861zrg/

So in this condition it won't work-

Comment: please create a [mcve]

Comment: The reason we ask you to create an mcve is because it will demonstrate that the code you've provided works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/ze6uvLtn/ - so you've not included something else in your code that's stopping it from working for you that we can only guess at (hence the 'complete' and 'verifiable' part).

Comment: From the help: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary **to reproduce it**.

Comment: Done added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get your code working however it would not unselect multiple cells of the same column. So I just modified it to this. Give it a try. Leave your CSS the same.

```
$("td").click(function(){
    $("td.selected").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: It is working. You forgot to select to use a Jquery library on the JSFiddle. 

https://jsfiddle.net/xf2n5q6s/

Also remember to reference Jquery in your HTML document as well if you might have not referenced it there also. Also when you reference your script in your HTML, it should be below your reference to the Jquery library.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you have one more row siblings() is not working for another row
try do this

```
$("td").click(function() {
  $(".selected").parent().find('td').removeClass("selected");
  $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
});
```

First you should find .selected class and you go to parent class and then you reach parent's td finally remove that you wanted class

Comment: Well that doesn't work for me...see my link above. I normaly don't use Javascript HTML and css. Pehraps I have something else wrong